# tcsh: print date 2 weeks ago in shell

Tags: date, tcsh

In tcsh on OpenBSD, I need to print a date two weeks ago.

E.g. if today is `2013-03-02`, I need to have `2013-02-16` printed out.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like `tcsh` allows executing nested commands, so, it looks like `ksh` has to be used.

```
date +%Y-%m-%d ; \
sh -c 'date -r $(expr $(date +%s) - $(expr 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 14)) +%Y-%m-%d'
2013-03-02
2013-02-16
```

We get the date in the number of seconds since Epoch in UTC, and calculate two weeks in seconds with `expr`, subtract, and pass these seconds back to `date` with the `-r` argument.

Not sure if there's a shorter solution, other than using `1209600` in place of `$(expr 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 14)`:

```
sh -c 'date -r $(expr $(date +%s) - 1209600) +%Y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: i have spent more than 10 mins to understand why it doesn't giving output in my shell.. then I saw your comment... :(

Answer (score 1):

This should work ( It works on GNU date. I am not very familiar with OpenBSD. So not sure if it works for you )

```
date -d "now - 14 days" +%Y-%m-%d
```

Comment: No, it obviously doesn't work.  But an interesting alternative for GNU/Linux users!