# What's the easiest way to rotate nginx log files monthly?

Tags: nginx, openbsd, logrotate, log-rotation

In OpenBSD, there's no `logrotate` in ports, and [`newsyslog`](http://mdoc.su/o/newsyslog) seems to have limited features as far as monthly rotation of a huge number of log files is concerned.

I have a lot of domains, a huge number of nginx log-files names like `/var/www/logs/*/*.{access,error}.log`.

I'm thinking a small shell script and cronjob. What would be the easiest way to rotate them all monthly, and append the prior month to the filename?

Comment: could you elaborate on the limited features of newsyslog? Also this question should be in serverfault IMO.

Comment: `newsyslog` doesn't let you postfix the date into the filename of the rotated files (`….access.log.2013-02`), and it also does not support wildcards.  This question deals with shell tricks (renaming files through shell), so I think stackoverflow is a more appropriate venue than serverfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following crontab should work:

```
0   0   1   *   *   /etc/nginx/logrotate.monthly.sh
```

Where /etc/nginx/logrotate.monthly.sh should have the following content:

```
find /var/www/logs/ -name "*log" -exec \
mv -i {} {}.`sh -c 'date -r $(expr $(date +%s) - 1209600) +%Y-%m'` \; ; \
kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
```

The `-i`/`--interactive` ("*prompt before overwrite*") option to `mv` is important to ensure that files don't get overwritten.  We get the date for the filename by moving today's date two weeks back (as per « [tcsh: print date 2 weeks ago in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183127/tcsh-print-date-2-weeks-ago-in-shell/15183128#15183128) »).

As [documented](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/logrotation/), "NGINX will re-open its logs in response to the USR1 signal."

Answer (score 0):

please check also this [misc@ thread](http://openbsd.7691.n7.nabble.com/Nginx-log-rotation-td220827.html).

(also keep in mind the caveat documented in the [FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq10.html#httpdchroot) about privseped apache and the need for a small time window upon the move.)

Comment: the misc@ thread does not address the issue with several dozen `/var/www/logs/…/….access.log` files for different domains